# Why, after deleting the button in the Android Android studio’s layout, does it still see it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-button

I removed the signUp button from my layout, android studio does not see it, but when the application starts, it appears.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".home.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/roundLayout"/>

    <com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.RoundRectView
        android:id="@+id/roundLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:shape_roundRect_bottomLeftRadius="22dp"
        app:shape_roundRect_bottomRightRadius="22dp"
        app:shape_roundRect_topLeftRadius="8dp"
        app:shape_roundRect_topRightRadius="8dp">

        <com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation.ChipNavigationBar
            android:id="@+id/chipNavigationMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:cnb_menuResource="@menu/bottom_menu"/>

    </com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.RoundRectView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the class code that calls activity_home. After I transferred the activity_home code to another layout, it worked, but immediately hung again and did not change.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import cheprasov.egor.cchat.R
import cheprasov.egor.cchat.fragments.favorite.favorites
import cheprasov.egor.cchat.fragments.home.homeFragment
import cheprasov.egor.cchat.fragments.settings.settings
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation.ChipNavigationBar

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var mAthListner: FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener
    private lateinit var menu: ChipNavigationBar
    private var fragment: Fragment? = null
    private lateinit var fragmentsHome: Fragment
    private lateinit var fragments: Fragment

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        init()

        if(fragment== null){
            val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            fragmentsHome = homeFragment()
            transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fragmentsHome)
            transaction.commit()
        }
        menu.setOnItemSelectedListener { id ->
            val option = when (id){
                R.id.home -> {
                    fragments = fragmentsHome
                    setFragment(fragments)
                }
                R.id.favorited -> {
                    fragments = favorites()
                    setFragment(fragments)
                }
                R.id.settings ->{
                    fragments = settings()
                    setFragment(fragments)
                }
                else -> finish()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fragment)
        transaction.commit()
    }


    private fun init(){
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        menu = findViewById(R.id.chipNavigationMenu)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle, outPersistentState: PersistableBundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        moveTaskToBack(true)
    }

    private fun signOut(){
        auth.signOut()
    }
}
```

[[image]]

[[image]]

[[image]]

Comment: are you using Instant Run? If you did not disable it - it might be causing this problem.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I do not have this setting

Comment: Try invalidating caches and restart and delete the apk file from android studio emulator...it should work

Comment: @DaveAAA It did not help

Comment: probably then you have multiple layout files, and this is not the one you are using in your Activity.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i have a single layout
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU05l.png

Comment: Disable instant run and then apply invalidate caches and restart on AS

Comment: He just wrote me a Duplicate resources error but I don’t understand it, look, I’m only sitting on one file. By the way, when I transferred everything to another file, everything worked, but I don’t understand what was happening with this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Quickest solution

Try restarting the app on the emulator using the run or debug icon on Android Studio.

#### Cleaner solution

1. Delete the app from emulator.
2. Delete the apk files created in the `app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`

Usually this problem happens in either of the following cases

1. When App is not rerun, only the layout is changed
2. When you use Instant run, sometimes it might not re-render instantly, It takes a few seconds..

Comment: It didn’t help, this Button still appears

Comment: Are you checking the same view from which you removed the button

Comment: Yes, now I have added another button but he does not see it

Comment: What is the name of the file given in the question ?

Comment: activity_home.xml

Comment: Can you also add the ActivityHome class code that loads the the activity_home.xml

Comment: There are no buttons in the fragments, I checked all the code files and nowhere is this button

Comment: Maybe try commenting out the fragments... And check if that helps

Comment: No it didn't help